# Provider hosted app still points to localhost

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have a problem with a provider hosted app I have developed.

In a test environment, the app ran on localhost.

Then I changed the startpage in AppManifest.xml

from

```
http://localhost/MyAppWeb/Pages/ClientWebPart1.aspx
```

to

```
http://myproduction/MyAppWeb/Pages/ClientWebPart1.aspx
```

and deployed for production use. So there shouldn't be any references to localhost now.

If I run the app as app part in a SharePoint page the url start with localhost
Are there still references to localhost yet? And where could they be?

Thanks

Comment: how did you deploy the app? Did you change the startpage on the manifest before or after the deploy?

Comment: I deployed the with Visual Studio click the green arrow. I changed the startpage in the manifest before the deploy. I've even tried to clean the solution after the change.

Comment: Try with the following steps then come back and let us know: 1) change the value on the manifest; 2) create the app package; 3) deploy that manually; 4) deploy the prj to Azure; 5) install the App; 6) test it

Comment: @Salvatore Di Fazio take into account that I'm on premises.I have some problems deploying the app manually.Can you give me some steps on how to do it? thanks

Comment: take a look on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179933(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: @Salvatore Di Fazio I have deployed the app manually from a catalog. The thing is (and this is a problem I already had faced) that doing so, I cannot add the app as app part in a page of my site collection. I had already questioned this site but I was only advised to publish directly into my site collection. Can you confirm me that you were able to add a provider hosted app to a page ?

Comment: you should do this with the app part

Comment: Yes, that's what I've tried. But the app is simply not there. The app is present in the site content but doesn't show app as add part. Some people in this site told me that couldn't add it as well. Can you do it in my same conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally sorted it out.
I had to publish through the site collection manually 
as though the catalog didn't allow me to add  the app part.
Then I had to change ~remoteAppUrl in elements.xml so that it pointed
to my url. Hope it helps.

Comment: if it solved ur problem, then plz mark it as answer.