# Deploying Sharepoint App 2013 using provider hosted website error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am having a lot of problem publishing my SharePoint App, the 2013 version should be an easier version to process but I can't seem to make it work.

I'm using currently Visual Studio 2013 and this are the steps I took

- Register on AppRegNew.aspx (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj687469.aspx)
- Publish through Visual Studio (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220044%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- Also I change my localhost to the pointed website ([Provider hosted app still points to localhost](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95519/provider-hosted-app-still-points-to-localhost))

Still I can't seem to properly publish my site, I kept having errors like this: [image]

Now I'm not sure which part of my step is wrong because I'm trying to deploy a newly created Sharepoint Site, and the localhost is fantastically working yet once I deploy I kept having this error

Edit*
This is the error that was shown:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference.  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

which is weird because when I run it localhost it works just fine

Comment: Do what the screen says so we can view the error. Edit your web.config and add the `customErrors` node. That will then give us the actual error that you're having.

Comment: Hi I edited my post so you can see clearer to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Follow this blog [article](http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2009/12/sharepoint-webconfig-how-to-show-full.html)  to view full error. Once you get the error details, you will be able to trace further, what's wrong with your configuration or code.

Comment: Actually I don't quite get the error, I mean I tried publishing another web then I change the AppManifest for the link of my site and still same error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set 'Copy Local' to True (do this in Visual Studio on your Web project) for assemblies that are required. 
This is also true for any Microsoft.SharePoint.* assemblies that you may be using.